# GeoServer Bulk TTF marks: my installed font is working when my legend uses my SLD style, but a WMS request of the same layer/style can't find it

Tags: geoserver, sld, font

I have an SLD style for a layer that uses Bulk TTF marks that point to a custom font I have installed on the host/geoserver. The font is showing up as available in the JVM fonts under Server Status and every symbol is showing in GetLegendGraphic, but in response to a WMS request I get the error:

> The specified mark ttf://myfont#0x0027 was not found!

Error in log:

> 22 011 19:11:54 TRACE  [renderer.style] - trying to render symbol ttf://myfont#0x0027
> 22 011 19:11:54 TRACE  [renderer.style] - rendering mark @ PointRenderer ttf://myfont#0x0027
> 22 011 19:11:54 TRACE  [renderer.style] - fetching mark of name ttf://myfont#0x0027
> 22 011 19:11:54 TRACE  [renderer.style] - Could not find the symbol, returning null
> 22 011 19:11:54 TRACE  [renderer.style] - fetching mark of name ttf://myfont#0x0027
> 22 011 19:11:54 DEBUG  [style.markwkt] - Trying to resolve symbol:ttf://myfont#0x0027
> 22 011 19:11:54 DEBUG  [style.markwkt] - Unable to resolve symbol
> 22 011 19:11:54 DEBUG  [style.windbarbs] - Trying to resolve symbol:ttf://myfont#0x0027
> 22 011 19:11:54 DEBUG  [style.windbarbs] - Unable to resolve symbol: ttf://myfont#0x0027
> 22 011 19:11:54 ERROR  [renderer.lite] - The specified mark ttf://myfont#0x0027 was not found!
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The specified mark ttf://myfont#0x0027 was not found!
> at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createMarkStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:637)
> at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createPointStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:593)
> at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createPointStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:473)
> at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyleInternal(SLDStyleFactory.java:328)
> at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:291)
> at org.geotools.renderer.style.SLDStyleFactory.createStyle(SLDStyleFactory.java:265)

When I open the font in Windows Character Map, there is definitely an item filled in for Unicode 27. GetLegendGraphic and GetMap are pointing to the same layer/style, so why can one find the font item and the other can't?

Comment: What exactly is in the log file when logging is turned up

Comment: I added it to my question, that is verbose logging, not sure if that's what you were looking for

Comment: I discovered the issue has something to do with Mark Factory Precedence in WMS Settings. The docs tell you to enable it and select TTFMarkFactory, however when I do this, only GetLegendGraphic works - GetMap gives the error above. When I unselect TTFMarkFactory, both GetLegendGraphic and GetMap work. Could this be an issue with my Geoserver installation or a bug in Geoserver?